# По каким конкретным признакам определяется вводное значение слова "наконец"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*Дождь зашуршал по крыше, перешёл через дорогу, ударил по ступеням и, **наконец**, стал набирать силу.*

Это пример с учебного сайта, где "наконец" обособлено как вводное слово. Тема: трудные случаи пунктуации при вводных словах.

Но вот точно ли оно вводное, по каким признакам это можно определить? И можно ли убедительно доказать ту или другую точку зрения?

**Дополнительный материал**

Учебный сайт Трудные случаи пунктуации при вводных словах  https://grammatika-rus.ru/trudnye-sluchai-punktuatsii-pri-vvodnyh-slovah-i-blizkih-im-po-znacheniyu/

Вводное НАКОНЕЦ = и еще: *Дождь зашуршал по крыше, перешёл через дорогу, ударил по ступеням и, наконец, стал набирать силу.*

Оригинальный текст (из него взято предложение).

*Через несколько минут ветер утих, и Лена услышала, как в сенях сонно и робко по очереди квохчут проснувшиеся куры. Потом стало слышно, как к избе подкрадывается дождь. **Вот он зашуршал по соломенной крыше дальнего сарая, вот перешел через дорогу, вот ударил по ступеням и наконец, захватив весь двор, стал набирать силу.***

**Комментарий**. Педагог изменяет предложение и полагает, что слово "наконец" становится вводным словом (в оригинальном тексте это обстоятельство).  На каком основании – вот в чем вопрос.

Можно ли найти такой **неопровержимый довод**, чтобы доказать ошибочность или правильность этого  мнения. Вот только этот довод должен быть очень убедительным, чтобы не оставалось ни тени сомнения. Неужели нет такого принципиального подхода к решению задачи, который однозначно отличал бы вводное слово от обстоятельства. **Природа вводных слов настолько загадочна?**

Comment: Шарон, загляните, пожалуйста, в тему про  тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, обособление не нужно, это не вводное, поскольку очень близко по смыслу к *в конце концов* в роли члена предложения [отсюда](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_282).

Неопровержимый довод? Ну хорошо, к *наконец,* насколько я понимаю, можно задать вопрос от *стал набирать силу.* Когда стал?

Comment: Поддерживаю. Это исковерканная цитата из повести С.П. Антонова, и только в одном издании (1948 г.) "наконец" обособлено, а во всех более поздних изданиях обособления нет.

Comment: Артем, спасибо за ответ и ваше мнение. Я дополнила вопрос некоторыми материалами – и теперь мне нужен неопровержимый довод, что это не вводное слово. Можете найти такое доказательство? Сравнение «наконец» и  «в конце концов» ничего нам не дает, так как в трех своих значениях (обстоятельство, вводное слово, междометие) они заменяют друг друга. Для доказательства нужно нечто иное.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Спасибо, что прокомментировали в теме про тире!

Comment: Артем, ваш довод очень частного характера, из него не следует однозначно, что это не вводное слово, то есть не прослеживается такая логика.  Кроме  того, у меня вообще появились сомнения  по поводу статуса слова. А появились они после внимательного прочтения статьи о слове "наконец". Даже захотелось уточнить общее определение вводных слов, как бы по-новому их определить или дополнить. Так вы уверены, что это не вводное слово? На  все сто?

Comment: На девяносто девять)

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, за участие. решила присоединиться к вашим 99 процентам.  Реальность - вот что всего главнее :) А мечтательность, сомнения и прочие вводные слова только осложняют жизнь.

Comment: Спасибо, Шарон!

Answer (score 3):

1. Вводные слова относятся **к группе модальных слов**.  Мода́льность (от ср. лат. modalis — модальный, лат. modus — мера, способ) — семантическая категория, выражающая **отношение** говорящего к содержанию его высказывания, целевую установку речи, отношение содержания высказывания к действительности.
   ***Отношение*** здесь – ключевое слово. Автор (или автор-рассказчик) как бы присутствует при совершении событий, комментирует их, оставляет какие-то заметки и впечатления.
2. Что нужно, чтобы слово «наконец»  однозначно считать вводным словом? Первое условие – **семантическое**. Это обязательно какой-то **ряд** мыслей, ощущений,  действий, где есть событие заключительное.  Если такого ряда нет, то и вводности тоже нет. Например:  «Купите  ***наконец*** приличный сервиз, а то вы подаете уже черт знает на чём». Это означает – пора купить, и это не вводное слово, так как нет нужной перечислительной семантики.
3. **Второе условие – модальность**, присутствие наблюдателя, который ведет свой субъективный счет происходящим событиям, предугадывает их развитие, дает им оценку, например: «И в таком положении молодые люди находились до конца августа, до того самого дня, когда, ***наконец***, Лапкин сделал Анне Семеновне предложение».
4. При описании реальных событий  объективность обычно находится на первом плане, а модальности, как правило, нет, например: «Казалось, дорога вела на небо, потому что, сколько глаз мог разглядеть, она всё поднималась и ***наконец*** пропадала в облаке».
5. Но вернемся к заданному предложению.

Исправленный вариант: *Дождь зашуршал по крыше, перешёл через дорогу, ударил по ступеням и, ***наконец***, стал набирать силу.*

Оригинальный вариант: *Через несколько минут ветер утих, и Лена услышала, как в сенях сонно и робко по очереди квохчут проснувшиеся куры. Потом стало слышно, как к избе подкрадывается дождь. Вот он зашуршал по соломенной крыше дальнего сарая, вот перешел через дорогу, вот ударил по ступеням и ***наконец***, захватив весь двор, стал набирать силу*.

В первом варианте модальность очевидно отсутствует, без контекста это обстоятельство, но только не вводное слово.

Больше оснований усмотреть модальное (субъективное) отношение в оригинальном тексте, где персонаж **предугадывает события, ожидает их, как бы заранее знает всю последовательность.** Там можно было бы обозначить вводность, однако автор не посчитал нужным сделать это.

Comment: *однако автор не посчитал нужным сделать это* — не уверен насчёт автора. Всё же в самом раннем из доступных в поисковике изданий "наконец" обособлено.

Comment: По поводу примера с ***сервизом***. Грамота говорит, что это пример необособления "наконец" со значением вводности. Здесь как раз четко видно *отношение* говорящего – недовольство: "а то вы подаете уже черт знает на чем".

Comment: @grizzly  Да, мне тоже хотелось бы обозначить здесь вводность, но истинную историю вопроса  вряд ли узнаешь. Хотя такие темы очень интересны, они как бы приближают к нам ушедшее время.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец   Александр, если нетерпение – это чувство, то почему оно тогда не междометие?  Почему его туда не берут? А сервиз, может, и надо бы купить, но если никто не собирался этого сделать, то и вводности здесь тогда тоже нет. И то, что слово не обособляется, тоже странно – видно, перешло в обычное обстоятельство и эмоции выражать перестало.